# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' when trying to split a column data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In this problem I am trying to split a column of data on the basis of space present in between the words.

When I am using the same code for other columns say "Body/Title" the code is working fine  but when trying with intended column "Tags" it is not working , giving me error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'.

```
df_no_dup.head()



start = datetime.now()
df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].apply(lambda text: len(text.split(" ")))

print("Time taken to run this cell :", datetime.now() - start)
df_no_dup.head()
```

[Error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvi4F.png)    [Output of df_no_dup.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiYLo.png)

Comment: Try `len(str(text).split(" "))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the date, try this :

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.now()
b = str(start).split(" ")
print(b)
>>['2019-09-03', '08:57:41.724462']
```

or simply :

```
start.hour
>> 8
start.year 
>> 2019
start.minute
>> 57
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].apply(lambda text: len(text.split(" ")) if text else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To split the text and store the number of words in a separate column try this:

```
df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].str.split(" ").str.len()
```